# Deny Use of Splitter in PropertyGrid Control

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, splitter

Is there any way to deny user from using Splitter in PropertyGrid Control. I go through all the properties of PropertyGrid Control, but I did not find to disable it. Is anything I am missing. Is there anyway to do it programatically. 
I am using C# Winforms VS2010.

Thanks

Comment: I had originally posted an answer to this, but it only related to a third party library. It looks like it is still possible to do what you want to do, but you'll have to reflect into some private properties and fiddle about with Win32 messages to do it I think - not all that nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the `PropertyGrid` control: [MSDN PropertyGrid](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGrid.cs,cbd4b5a9181135d5)

To prevent the horizontal divider behavior, override the OnMouseDown and OnMouseMove methods. To prevent the vertical divider behavior, one approach is to use a IMessageFilter and consume the mouse events when the location of the mouse is near the divider location.

```
public class MyForm3 : Form, IMessageFilter {

    PropertyGrid pg = new MyPropertyGrid { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    Control gridView = null;
    MethodInfo miSplittlerInside = null;

    public MyForm3() {
        Controls.Add(pg);
        pg.SelectedObject = new Button { Text = "Bob" };

        var f = typeof(PropertyGrid).GetField("gridView", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        gridView = (Control) f.GetValue(pg);
        miSplittlerInside = gridView.GetType().GetMethod("SplitterInside", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        if (m.HWnd == gridView.Handle) {
            if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE || m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK) {
                Point pt = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
                bool inside = (bool) miSplittlerInside.Invoke(gridView, new Object[] { pt.X, pt.Y });
                if (inside) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    class MyPropertyGrid : PropertyGrid {
        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs me) {
            //base.OnMouseMove(me);
            // do nothing, prevent user from moving the split bar
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs me) {
            //base.OnMouseDown(me);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Not calling the base methods will have the side effect that any listeners for those events will not be triggered.

Clarification: The code prevents the purple splitter. Is your question referring to the orange or purple?

[image]

Comment: Did you try this?  Has no effect.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes I did. It seemed to work, I'll double check though.

Comment: @LarsTech I double checked using 35/40/45 and it definitely disables being able to grab the divider bar. The mouse no longer turns into the `HSplit` cursor, and clicking on the divider has no effect.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what's 35/40/45 supposed to mean?

Comment: @LarsTech `.NET35 .NET40 .NET45`.

Comment: Oh.  `myPropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new StudentClass();` and I can still interact with the divider.  Windows 10 in case it matters.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, I tested with and without an object, and the divider is disabled. Silly question, but can you confirm `new MyPropertyGrid()` and it didn't autocomplete using just `new PropertyGrid()` ?

Comment: I double checked.  My form is using the MyProjectGrid class.

Comment: @Loathing I used your code. But there is no change. I am able to use Splitter. I have to change anything in my framework? I am using .Net 4 Client Profile. Or if possible just send me source file, I'll check with that.

Comment: @Gopi Maybe I am misunderstanding the question. Can you clarify which splitter needs to be disabled? Or something completely different? I posted an image above.

Comment: @Loathing Sorry for not mention that in my Question. I am talking about the Orange color line

Comment: Obviously, I was always looking at the orange divider.  Good job.